# Centering a table header

Tags: html, css

I'm having issues centering a single table header.
Below is the table[a snapshot of the table Im trying to center Its header](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z3OhI.png).
[A snapshot of the HTML code for the table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hkcst.png)

Comment: Please [use markup to post code](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code), instead of screenshots. If you wish to show a Codepen that reproduces the issue, please include a hyperlink to the Codepen itself. This helps people give you answers without working hard to type things you already typed.

Answer (score 0):

lots of ways to do this.  I would use flex.  as you can see where id='zero' the solution by カメロン does NOT work

```css
#one{
   text-align:center;
   width:100%;
}

#two{
   margin:0 auto;
}

#three{
   display:flex;
   justify-content:center;
}

#zero th{
width:100%;
text-align:center;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <th> one</th>
    <th>two</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>cat</td>
    <td>dog</td>
  </tr>
</table>

<table id='zero'>
  <tr>
    <th> one</th>
    <th>two</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>cat</td>
    <td>dog</td>
  </tr>
</table>

<table id='one'>
  <tr>
    <th> one</th>
    <th>two</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>cat</td>
    <td>dog</td>
  </tr>
</table>

<table id='two'>
  <tr>
    <th> one</th>
    <th>two</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>cat</td>
    <td>dog</td>
  </tr>
</table>

<div id='three'>
<table>
  <tr>
    <th> one</th>
    <th>two</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>cat</td>
    <td>dog</td>
  </tr>
</table>
</div>
```